# What is needed to see NAS drive?

Tags: networking

If I use Windows XP the drive is seen in the network it is not seen in ubuntu's network.
I do know and can use Connect to a Server but the question is really not about that. I would like to know if the windows functionality can be obtained in ubuntu?

Comment: I think the question is: "why doesn't Ubuntu show the NAS somewhere? Why do I have to connect to it?"

Comment: Yes and the router if that can be done

Answer (score 2):

You could [mount it permanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and it would just look like another drive.

Or when you use the "Connect to server" dialogue, just tick the bookmark checkbox and you gain a shortcut to it in your places. Clicking this when it's not mounted will get it to mount.

Comment: Suspect this may not work as I am relying on a wifi connecton and won't fstab be run before log in?

Comment: Okay, you can just add a bookmark then. It will mount as you need it.

Comment: Can anyone offer an insight as to why Windows can see it automatically and ubuntu can't?

Comment: For sure, if it can be done "manually" it can be done automatically too, maybe just nobody missed it yet, what you want here :) Anyway you mentioned wifi connection: you can try to use a script which is activated when network is brought up: `/etc/network/if-up.d/` directory hold such a scripts, you can create a new one with the mount statement you wanna use (you can even put into /etc/fstab set to "noauto") and you can say "mount ...yourmountpoint...." in that script.

Comment: Yes your right could go this way but what I was hoping for was to make the places Network system have the same functionality as windows. At the moment it says no shares available which is true but why can't it see my nas drive and my router?